# How to generate .resx file dynamically in C# in human readable format

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I was trying to generate .resx file using **ResourceWriter** but file generated is not in readable format

```
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Resources.resx";
            ResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter(filePath);
            writer.AddResource("Hello", "World");
```

With this code I achieved this.

[image]

But I want resource file to be in this format.
[image]

How can I achieve this dynamically.

I tried this piece of code, after seeing Markus's answer but no luck.

```
 public void CreateResx()
        {
            var resxWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(filePath);

            resxWriter.AddResource(new ResXDataNode("Hello", "World"));

            var dataNode = new ResXDataNode("Hello", "People")
            {
                Comment = "dummy"
            };

            resxWriter.AddResource(dataNode);
        }
```

Comment: \*sigh* is there images of text again?

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunately not that straight forward.

You need to add individual `ResxDataNode`s to the file.

I use the following code to generate my RESX files:

```cs
public static byte[] CreateResxContent(Query query)
{
      using (var resxStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
           var resxWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(resxStream);

           if (query.Elements.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (var element in query.Elements)
               {
                   var dataNode =
                        new ResXDataNode(element.Entries[TextIdIndex], element.Entries[TranslationIndex])
                        {
                            Comment = element.Entries[DescriptionIndex]
                        };

                   resxWriter.AddResource(dataNode);
              }
         }

         resxWriter.Close();

         return resxStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

So in your case changing

`writer.AddResource("Hello", "World");`

to

`writer.AddResource(new ResXDataNode("Hello", "World"));`

might already do the trick.

Comment: But when I try to open .resx file generated through visual studio, it says _ResX file Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: xsd:complexType, xsd:element, xsd:choice, xsd:complexType, xsd:element, xsd:schema, root. Line 101, position 76. cannot be parsed_.

Comment: Please add the rest of your code to your question, maybe it's a matter of flushing/saving/closing of streams and files.

Comment: Are are there different types of .resx file? Beacuse when generated dynamically generates unreadable resx file whereas if made manually it generates in readable form.